# Fullcalendar dayrender - asynchronously behaviour

Tags: javascript, promise, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm using [fullcalender](https://fullcalendar.io/) to show at my users all his bookings. 
I'm using the fullcalendar callback **dayRender**

```
<script>
    //load calendar
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      locale: 'en',
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
      },
      dayRender: function(date, cell) {
            $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: '/user/bookings/'+'?date='+date.format('D-M-Y'),
              success: function(response){

                  var result = $.parseJSON(response);

                  if(result.length){
                    $(cell).addClass('bg-info')
                    $(cell).append(result.length)
                  }
              },
              error: function(error) {
                console.log(error)
              }
            })
      }
    });
  </script>
```

So, for each day I call an ajax, and print the number of bookings in that days, also I add a class for background color of the cell.
My problem is that the behaviour is sincroniusly, so the ajax of 2 Jannuary is called only after the 1 Jannuary ajax has response. And this is very slow. How can i do this in a asynchronously way?

I'm not so skilled with JS, but I presume is about the dayRender() behaviour.

Comment: This is not a sensible or recommended way to load events. Instead, just load all of them at once, for the entire time range which is visible on your calendar at that moment. FullCalendar can help you with this. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function (these are two alternative approaches to automating the correct download of events, depending on your exact requirements. The first one is simpler, since fullCalendar will run the AJAX for you, it should not be hard for you to change your server code to comply with that, I think).

Comment: this is perfect for me. Thanks!